# Not getting the expected results from for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble with a if statement in a for loop where the items are not fitting under the h1 like i would of expected it's almost like the if is been missed the first go and that messes things up

Here is some example code and the jsfiddle to go with it http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/714036/

```js
var jsonOut = [{
    "check": [{
        "name": "Singapore",
      },
      {
        "name": "SanFrancisco",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sydney",
      }
    ],
    "timestamp": 1535678338,
  },
  {
    "check": [{
        "name": "Singapore",
      },
      {
        "name": "SanFrancisco",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sydney",
      }
    ],
    "timestamp": 1535678338,
  },
  {
    "check": [{
        "name": "Singapore",
      },
      {
        "name": "SanFrancisco",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sydney",
      }
    ],
    "timestamp": 1535594440,
  },
  {
    "check": [{
        "name": "Singapore",
      },
      {
        "name": "SanFrancisco",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sydney",
      }
    ],
    "timestamp": 1535594440,
  },
]

var content = ''

var lastDate = 0

for (var i = 0; i < jsonOut.length; i++) {

  var testDate = new Date(jsonOut[i].timestamp * 1000);

  var contentNow = ''

  var ResultName = ''
  var h1marker = ''

  for (var j = 0; j < jsonOut[i].check.length; j++) {
    ResultName = ResultName + '' + jsonOut[i].check[j].name + '<br>'
    contentNow = testDate + '<br>' + ResultName
  }

  if (jsonOut[i].timestamp != lastDate) {
    h1marker = "<h1>" + testDate.getDate() + "</h1>"
    lastDate = jsonOut[i].timestamp
  }

  content = h1marker + contentNow + content

}

$("#tests").html(content)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tests">

</div>
```

Comment: You don't need jsFiddle when you have Stack Snippets! `:D` And sorry, didn't understand your question well. What's happening and what are you expecting?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  When you step through this in your debugger, where specifically does the behavior first differ from what you expect?  Which line of code produces an unexpected result?  What were the relevant runtime values of the variables used on that line?  What was the expected result?  Why?

Comment: I don't  clearly understand what exact output are you expecting ? can you please elaborate your issue

Comment: Running your code looks good to me. The day (from the date) is large then the additional information for the day is under it. Providing an expected output would go a long way in understanding what you mean by *"items are not fitting under the h1 [tag]"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your if-statement at all. Your code at this part

`content = h1marker + contentNow + content`

Puts the new content IN FRONT of the old, therefore your second entry for each date is above the header "30".

Change it to  `content = content + h1marker + contentNow` like in the following snippet:

```js
var jsonOut = [{
    "check": [{
        "name": "Singapore",
      },
      {
        "name": "SanFrancisco",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sydney",
      }
    ],
    "timestamp": 1535678338,
  },
  {
    "check": [{
        "name": "Singapore",
      },
      {
        "name": "SanFrancisco",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sydney",
      }
    ],
    "timestamp": 1535678338,
  },
  {
    "check": [{
        "name": "Singapore",
      },
      {
        "name": "SanFrancisco",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sydney",
      }
    ],
    "timestamp": 1535594440,
  },
  {
    "check": [{
        "name": "Singapore",
      },
      {
        "name": "SanFrancisco",
      },
      {
        "name": "Sydney",
      }
    ],
    "timestamp": 1535594440,
  },
]

var content = ''

var lastDate = 0

for (var i = 0; i < jsonOut.length; i++) {

  var testDate = new Date(jsonOut[i].timestamp * 1000);

  var contentNow = ''

  var ResultName = ''
  var h1marker = ''

  for (var j = 0; j < jsonOut[i].check.length; j++) {
    ResultName = ResultName + '' + jsonOut[i].check[j].name + '<br>'
    contentNow = testDate + '<br>' + ResultName
  }

  if (jsonOut[i].timestamp != lastDate) {
    h1marker = "<h1>" + testDate.getDate() + "</h1>"
    lastDate = jsonOut[i].timestamp
  }

  content = content + h1marker + contentNow

}

$("#tests").html(content)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tests">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that got it, I can not believe the fix was so obvious and how I missed it.